# GPS Logger Recommendation

Tags: gps, data

I have one more day left in Bangkok and electronic equipment is so much cheaper than in South Africa, so this might be my cue to buy a GPS logger for when I go record sounds.

Can anyone recommend a good-ish, cheap one that works on mac ( with the provided software)? I want to interface with Max/MSP so I need to be able to access the information independently from the provided software.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm actually a bit surprised there aren't any GPS-enabled field recorders on the market. I think for several fields (scientific & documentary recording, holiday recordings etc. etc.) this is a huge market niche...

Comment: @Julian yes, I agree! I'm busy trying to write software that will allow me to combine sounds and photos with the GPS location from the logger. 

Comment: @Andrew great! keep us up to date about that...

Comment: @Julian I actually just passed a bunch of big hurdles today! So lets hope it all works out :-) 

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a question I'm able to answer :)

max msp can receive data from serial object through RS-232 that means that a bluetooth GPS would be the cheapest option. I have a Holux GPSlim 236 which is quite cheap and easy to connect with max. The only thing is that this kind of gps don't have a screen or display to check on field where are you. Anyway, I think any of the Holux Wireless GPS Receiver / Data Logger are ok for the work,.... check out the web:

http://www.holux.com/JCore/en/products/products_list.jsp?pno=2

If you wanna spend more money and have a fancy thing I would go for Garmin one or Magellan and check out that they have USB connections and so on,.... BUt i'm not sure if the connectivity with max will work out.

yeah!
:)

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I shall start the hunt tomorrow :-) 